# C++11 thread hangs on locking mutex

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, locking, mutex

Using C++11 `std::thread`, `std::mutex`, I'm writing a simple worker thread.
However, I got a strange hang issue in locking `std::mutex`, which looks like both threads (main and worker thread) are trying to lock a mutex, but both are blocked.

Here's the full code

```
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
std::condition_variable cv;
std::mutex m;
std::thread t;
bool shouldExit = false;
std::list<int> jobs;

void thread_func()
{
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
  while (!shouldExit) {
    while (jobs.empty() && !shouldExit) {
      cv.wait(lock);
    }
    // Do some stuff
    if (jobs.empty()) {
      continue;
    }
    // Get a job and do something with it
    if (!lock.owns_lock()) {
      lock.lock();  // <<<< Worker thread hang here
    }
    auto j = std::move(jobs.front());
    jobs.pop_front();
    lock.unlock();
    std::cout << "Do something with job " << j << std::endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
  }
}

int main()
{
  t = std::thread(thread_func);

  for (int i = 1; i < 100; ++i) {
    std::cout << "Push to job " << i << std::endl;
    {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m); // <<<< main thread hang here
    jobs.push_back(i);
    cv.notify_one();
    }
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
  }

  // To wait for thread exit
  shouldExit = true;
  cv.notify_one();
  t.join();
  return 0;
}
```

I'm compiling the code using below command on Ubuntu 14.04

```
g++ -std=c++11 -g -O0 -pthread -o testthread testthread.cpp
```

The executing result is typically like this:

```
$ ./testthread
Push to job 1
Do something with job 1
Push to job 2
Do something with job 2
Push to job 3
Push to job 4
```

The interesting part is, when I move one line code of sleeping-1ms in main thread into the `lock_guard` like below, the issue is gone.

```
  for (int i = 1; i < 100; ++i) {
    std::cout << "Push to job " << i << std::endl;
    {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
    jobs.push_back(i);
    cv.notify_one();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1)); // Moved into lock_guard
    }
  }
```

I could not figure out why.
Could you help to explain the behavior of the code and what I did wrong?

[Update] I know re-writing the worker thread in certain way could fix the issue. But I still would like to know in the original code what exactly happens when the two threads are locking the mutex but both are blocked.

Comment: declare `shouldExit` as `std::atomic<bool>` as it needs to be protected... and I see there are many synchronization issues.

Comment: I tried to make `shouldExit` as `std::atomic<bool>`, but the result is the same. It reproduces at [online ideone](https://ideone.com/Tej9kw) as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is undefined behavior to call `cv.wait` with `lock` not locked.  Add this assert:

```
while (!shouldExit) {
  assert(lock.owns_lock());    // <------ add this
  while (jobs.empty() && !shouldExit) {
    cv.wait(lock);
  }
```

libc++ will throw from the `wait` if `!lock.owns_lock()`, but I don't know what other implementations will do.

Comment: That assert will almost always fire in the OP's code; Though `std::unique_lock` will have the mutex locked before entering that "loop condition", there is a code path to that loop "loop condition" that breaks the invariant of `std::unique_lock`. Though I recommended a better way. You are the expert here... You may please want to review my answer

Comment: @WhiZTiM:  You've got a pretty good answer, and you've put a lot of work into it.  I'd be nervous about calling `cv.notify_one()` from `main` without a gratuitous lock/unlock from the main thread.  And as long as you're doing that, `main` can set `shouldExit` under that lock.  And since `thread_func` reads `shouldExit` under the lock, `shouldExit` would then not need to be atomic.  All that being said, there exist plenty of applications where the manual unlock/lock sequence during processing is needed and the right thing to do, so your first solution is not inherently bad.  Continuing ...

Comment: Here is code I've written with the unlock/lock pattern: https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/src/mutex.cpp#L260-L262  though admittedly this code had to use a C interface.  But I'm sure you can still recognize the pattern.  In this example it is critical that the mutex be unlocked while executing the client's function.

Comment: OK, I just noticed that "Calling std::condition_variable::wait() if lock.mutex() is not locked by the current thread is undefined behavior." Thanks!

Comment: @HowardHinnant, Thanks for reviewing my answer. I have also looked through your libcxx mutex implementation and skimmed through some other threaded library projects, and I recognize the pattern. Thanks for correcting my previous bias to that pattern! >> Likewise on the atomic `shoudExit` and `cv.notify_one()`

Answer (score 4):

You have serious and classic bugs in your code....

First, please see the annotated/numbered comments. I will refer to them

```
void thread_func()
{
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);        // <---- {1}
  while (!shouldExit) {                        // <---- {2}
    while (jobs.empty() && !shouldExit) {      // <---- {3}
      cv.wait(lock);
    }
    // Do some stuff
    if (jobs.empty()) {
      continue;
    }

    if (!lock.owns_lock()) {
      lock.lock();                             // <---- {4}
    }
    auto j = std::move(jobs.front());
    jobs.pop_front();
    lock.unlock();                             // <---- {5}
    std::cout << "Do something with job " << j << std::endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
  }
}
```

{1} This is good.... see you defeating the aim of this in {5}

{2} `shouldExit` should be an atomic bool. Else you will have race conditions

{3} At some point in execution, this condition will be tested while not holding the lock, see the unlock statement in {5}. Hence, you have yet another race condition.

{4} With an unlocked mutex, between the time you test the lock and the time you issue lock, the mutex could be acquired, causing this to perpetually wait here.

{5} Makes the mutex unlocked for the next execution of the loop... serious race conditions and deadlock will happen.

## Patching up your current solution... {Bad but working patch... read further}

Just add `lock.lock()` to the last line to your `thread_func()`

like this....

```
void thread_func()
{
    .....more code omitted
    ........
    lock.unlock();                            
    std::cout << "Do something with job " << j << std::endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));

    lock.lock();   //YOUR NEW LINE
  }
}
```

The addition restores the loop back to the original state of a mutex being locked before entry.... Note that there is another code path to reach the entry of the loop... where you had `continue` statement... Whenever a `std::condition_variable::wait()` returns, the lock is always relocked, so invariant is still maintained...

Now your code works!! Yay!!! ... But it still smells a lot!
`std::cout` is thread-safe but the output isn't synchronized, therefore, you may have interleaved characters...

Sidelining the problem with `std::cout` How to do it properly? Check this code (also please see the comments)

```
void thread_func()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
    while (!shouldExit)    // this is redundant, so I removed it in the final code
    {
        while (jobs.empty() && !shouldExit)
        {
            cv.wait(lock, []{ return !jobs.empty(); } );
        }
        // Do some stuff
        auto j = std::move(jobs.front());
        jobs.pop_front();
        //cout is thread-safe but not synchronized
        //std::cout << "Do something with job " << j << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
    }
}
```

In most common cases I know of, its always better to test your "ready to proceed" conditions inside [`std::condition_variable::wait()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait).

---

To put it all together for you.... Here is a better version

```
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <atomic>

std::condition_variable cv;
std::mutex m;
std::mutex mxa;   //for std::cout locking
std::thread t;
std::atomic<bool> shouldExit;
std::list<int> jobs;

namespace detail
{

    std::ostream& safe_print()
    {
        return std::cout;
    }

    template<typename T, typename... Args>
    std::ostream& safe_print(T&& t, Args&&... args)
    {
        std::cout << t;
        return safe_print(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
}

template<typename... Args>
std::ostream& println(Args&&... args)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(mxa);
    auto&& x = detail::safe_print(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return x;
}

void thread_func()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
    while (jobs.empty() && !shouldExit)
    {
        cv.wait(lock, []{ return !jobs.empty(); } );
    }
    // Do some stuff
    auto j = std::move(jobs.front());
    jobs.pop_front();
    //std::cout << "Do something with job " << j << std::endl;
    println("Do something with job ", j);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
}

int main()
{
    shouldExit = false;
    //safe_print("This is really funny ", 43, '\n');
    t = std::thread(thread_func);

    for (int i = 1; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        //std::cout << "Push to job " << i << std::endl;
        println("Push to Job ", i);
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m); // <<<< main thread doesn't hang here again
            jobs.push_back(i);
            cv.notify_one();
        }
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
    }

    // To wait for thread exit
    shouldExit = true;
    cv.notify_one();
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Regarding {4} "With an unlocked mutex, between the time you test the lock and the time you issue lock, the mutex could be acquired, causing this to perpetually wait here." Why both threads are blocked during locking the mutex? Probably as @Howard Hinnant's comment, "It is undefined behavior to call cv.wait with lock not locked."

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, it really helps! But I will mark @Howard Hinnant's answer as accepted since it explains the root cause of my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try rewrite your worker thread like this:

```
void thread_func()
{
  while (!shouldExit) 
  {
    int j ;
    {  
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);  // lock object inside while
      while (jobs.empty() && !shouldExit) {
        cv.wait(lock);
      }
      // Do some stuff
      if (jobs.empty()) {
        continue;
      }
      j = jobs.front(); 
      jobs.pop_front();
    } // lock goes out of scope
    std::cout << "Do something with job " << j << std::endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
  }
}
```

As you can see j is no longer moved, you could encapsulate the section after `int j ;` inside a function to get the same effect.

The main idea of the rewrite is avoid messing with lock's member function and use it by letting constructor/destructor making the locking job.

[Seems to work...](https://ideone.com/41DHC3)

Comment: While the code works, the explanation of what is wrong with original code is unsatisfactory.

Comment: Although it works, I still do not know what is wrong with my original code?

Comment: Your original code unlocks the lock before the "Do something with job" line and then gets back at the beginning of the while with an unlocked lock. The code I posted gets the lock on mutex every time you enter the beginning of while.

Comment: Keep in mind that the while will be executed 100 times before exiting.

Comment: @marom The idea is to only-lock the part of the code regarding operations on `jobs`, so the `unlock` and re-`lock` part is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem here:

```
   while (jobs.empty() && !shouldExit) {
      cv.wait(lock);
    }
    // Do some stuff
    if (jobs.empty()) {
      continue;
    }
```

When you wake up, you own the lock. However, by calling `continue` you loose any chance of releasing it.

Comment: OK, but typically when the code run into this continue, it means `shouldExit` is true, so it will go out of the while loop, and the thread function returns, and the lock is released by `std::unique_lock`'s destructor.

Comment: And I tried to unlock the `mutex` before `continue`, the issue remains. ```if (jobs.empty()) {
      if (lock.owns_lock()) {
        lock.unlock();
      }
      continue;
    }```

Comment: What is the reason of all this 'if owns lock'? You are **guaranteed** to own the lock after wait.